# Linux : Count Open Files for Process

Tags: linux, unix, process, lsof, limits

How can I check how many open files are currently used?

Checking on PM2 is just an example:

I found the PID:

```
ps aux | grep pm2 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Checked that there is a limit of 65536 openfiles:

```
# cat /proc/16305/limits | grep 'Max open files'
```

Max open files            65536                65536                files

This limit is set via systemd:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/pm2.service.d/nofile_limit.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65536
```

I know that I can check how many files are open based on the user:

```
lsof -u UserName | wc -l
252
```

PM2 is running on diffrent user than PM2, and when I checked the limit on that user it is ridiculously small, so something is wrong here..

How can I check how many open files are currently used if the limit is set and managed by systemd?

When I wrote this post I came with idea, maybe this could be a solution to my own problem:

```
lsof | grep ' userName ' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | wc -l
2348
```

What do you think?

Comment: Can you just enumerate `/proc/pid/fd` for a given pid?

Answer (score 2):

If you want check for one process which you know pid try this

```
ls /proc/$pid/fd/ | wc -l
```